# Open A Particular Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am wondering how to open a particular accordion (actually a toggle).

Here is my jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
        //Add Inactive Class To All Accordion Headers
        $('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

        //Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
        $('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');

        // The Accordion Effect
        $('.accordion-header').click(function () {
            if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
                $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
                $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
                $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
            }

            else {
                $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
                $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });​
```

What happens now is that on page load the very first item opens. How can I set it to where, say, the second items open?

I have a Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bbyrdhouse/LjDBa/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automatically open the second accordion, change the first lines to this:

```
$('.accordion-header').eq(1).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
$('.accordion-content').eq(1).slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');
```

[`eq(1)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) will locate the second item in the matched elements (the index is zero based). If you want to open the last accordion, use [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) instead of [`eq(1)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adrianonantua/LjDBa/1/